# How to pass parameter between two project asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have C# page to send parameters to an webservice and the webservice is not in the same project. I know the url of the webservice. How can I pass the parameters, I've tried the code below

```
 Response.Redirect(" http://url/mobileservice.asmx/kioskOyunKodu?kioskkod='+kioskID+',kioskKodEncryped='+encodedCode+',okulno='+txt_StudentID.Text'");
```

Is there any other way to solve this issue when I execute that line I got

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Url is wrongly formed and you have included special character in your redirect URL. That why you received A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) exception.

Below is how URL are formed with querystring.

```
Response.Redirect("http://url/mobileservice.asmx/kioskOyunKodu?kioskkod="+ kioskID + "&kioskKodEncryped=" + encodedCode + "&okulno=" + txt_StudentID.Text);
```

Comment: Is there any change on the querystring because kioskID and encoded Code are string, okulno is an integer?

Comment: All parameters are identified as string there nothing like bool,int or decimal when something is passed into querystring.

Comment: Welcome, pleasure helping you out :)

Comment: May I ask another question? This process is working right now but it appears on the screen, can I do it as background process. I do not want display anything.

Comment: Didn't understood what you have said in previous comment *it appears on the screen* but if you want to make an async call then you can use ScriptManager or ClientScript, for server operation you can use Thread.

Comment: I have a button click event to send parameters but when I click on the button it opens a new window because code redirects me that link. I want that operation as background process. I do not want to display redirected url

Comment: For that you will need Lightbox commonly known as popup and do all your operation here. Your requirement for redirecting to specific page is no longer required, here you can open the required page inside a popup.

Comment: I've used Webrequest method that worked but I will keep your suggestion in mind. It's will help me later. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space for creativity for this particular case:

1. Change your site security policies that let you pass parameters with special characters with you `GET` request
2. in case if your both project have an access to a shared resouce like database, you can push all the bunch of parameters in a single table with uniqie `ID` and then you can pass the id as a parameter between your service url
3. You can use a `POST` reqest with data